# identity over column id is not working well

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem when using the identity automatic sequence.
In the beginning everything works well but after it starts to show bigger numbers

```
ID NAZIV         KATEGORIJA                    OPIS              OBAVLJENO
-- --------------- ------------------- ----------------------------- ---------
21 osmi zadatak    pl/sql blok        kreiranje anonimnog pl/sql blo  n
                       ka

 1 prvi zadatak    kreiranje tablespac kreiranje tablespace-a sa odre y
           -a              djenim karakteristikama

 2 drugi zadatak   kreiranje usera     kreiranje usera sa odredjenim  y
                       karakteristikama

 3 treci zadatak   kreiranje tabele    kreiranje tabele sa testnim po y
                       dacima

 4 cetvrti zadatak kreiranje b-tree in kreianje b-tree indexa nad kol y
           dexa            onom id

 5 peti zadatak    kreiranje sequence  kreiranje sequence seq_zadaci_ y
                       id

 6 sesti zadatak   ubacivanje podataka ubacivanje podataka u tabelu i y
            u tabelu        izvrsiti nekoliko izmena

 7 sedmi zadatak   kreiranje paketa    kreiranje paketa sa uskladiste n
                       nim procedurama
```

So far everything worked well, so I called all the data in the table:

```
SQL> insert into zadaci (naziv, kategorija, opis, obavljeno)
  2  values ('osmi zadatak', 'pl/sql blok', 'kreiranje anonimnog pl/sql bloka', 'n');
```

Comment: Sequence numbers are not guaranteed to be sequential without gaps.  Get used to it.

Comment: You've probably inserted some data and then rolled back. Or are using RAC. This is normal.

Answer (score 1):

An identity column uses a sequence in the background.

[From the concepts guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/partitions-views-and-other-schema-objects.html#GUID-29E19A46-D91F-4EEB-BD0C-E65A89F2F59B):

> Individual sequence numbers can be skipped if they were generated and used in a transaction that was ultimately rolled back.
>
> WARNING:
>
> If your application requires a gap-free set of numbers, then you cannot use Oracle sequences. You must serialize activities in the database using your own developed code.

Gaps are expected, and can be caused by inserts being rolled back, manual calls to the sequence (unlikely with an identity column), or cached values can be lost if a DB crashes.

In addition if you have a RAC cluster then each instance will have its own cache of values and statements running on the instances will assign values from their own cache, so the identities may not even be strictly sequential if you compare with say a timestamp value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, is it possible that the bug is somewhere in the linux system.

Comment: How can I fix a sequence without wiping out data from the table, I do not use rac.

Comment: What bug? This is just how it works. Also not sure what you want to 'fix'? You can never guarantee the sequence is gapless (even if you disable the cache, which will hurt performance).

Comment: @Petar: there is no bug here. This is how sequence were designed to work.

Comment: I want to fill id linearly

Comment: "If your application requires a gap-free set of numbers, then you cannot use Oracle sequences." Identity columns are (usually, supposed to be) synthetic keys, so why does it matter if there are gaps? You shouldn't have logic or behaviour reliant on a synthetic key value.

Comment: I'm worried that it's the first place 21 and I called it the last one, it should be number eight

Comment: If that is all the data in your table then Oracle either thinks that was the 21st insert and the 8th-20th were rolled back, or the rows inserted 8th-20th have since been deleted; or the inserts were done on different RAC nodes; or you had a crash somewhere. I don't know how many different ways to say it - this is normal behaviour. The actual key/identity values should not matter to you.